# Audio when connecting to and from monitor

Tags: display, audio, bash, thunderbolt

I have my monitor **Dell P2415Q** connected through thunderbolt and the speakers connected through aux to my Dell monitor, so that I don't then have 5 cables going into my mac instead of 4 (Dell USB Hub, Ethernet(Thunderbolt), Charger and Monitor (Thunderbolt)).

The problem is, when I connect my mac with the Thunderbolt the audio option to choose the monitor as the output in system preferences, is only sometimes there (when it is, it works seamlessly). Also sometimes the audio plays from different applications on my laptop and everything else on the speakers.

The only way to get it to work is by running:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

and one time I ran that my whole system crashed with a terrifying error message from apple, so I am pretty scared to do that now.

What would you recommend I do?

Comment: This **isn't** a Thunderbolt monitor.  It has DisplayPort, mini DisplayPort and HDMI.  Are you connecting via DisplayPort or HDMI?  I'm guessing HDMI since DP doesn't carry audio, but need to confirm.

Comment: Thunderbolt is a DisplayPort? And it does carry audio. This is 100% a software issue

Comment: I was mistaken...DisplayPort does carry audio.  However, Thunderbolt **carries** DisplayPort signals.  So are you connecting to Display Port or HDMI?  Have you tried just turning off the monitor for a few seconds then turning it back on?

Comment: @Allan haha yes I have and it sometimes works! I am looking for a definitive answer you see :)